# Cannot call value of non function type Data? SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

Tried almost every solution found here. But couldn't solve this issue.I am using Alamofire and swiftyJSON.

[image: Screen shot]

**Code below:**

```
upload.responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
                print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
                print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
                print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result
                print("Result Value: \(response.result.value.debugDescription)")
                spinner.stopAnimating()
                print(response.error.debugDescription)
                //print("\(response.result.error)")
                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    if let result = response.result.value {
                        print("JSON: \(result)") // serialized json response
                        let json = JSON(result)
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: Don't Put screen shot , add your code

Comment: replace `response.result.value` with `result1` object

Comment: @JonSnow - Its one and the same.. anyway it was result1 at first. while trying solutions i changed it.. will update question with code

Comment: Didn't get you !!! , i can see issue regarding to `Data?` where expected type might be `Data` and you have unwrap it  in `result1` then why you are using `response.result.value` rather

Comment: Doesnt matter.. I am intializing result with response.result.value.. its one and the same.. the if condition just checks for nil

Comment: if let is not just for checking nil  different then simple if condition  anyway please try    to print it      `String.init(data: result1, encoding: .utf8)` May be your response has issue

Comment: response has issue as in? this isnt a runtime error.. getting this error in xcode's editor..

Comment: Try  `if let result = response.result.value as? Data`

Comment: @JonSnow Tried.. giving same error.. Thanks for your help.. :)

Comment: Surprisingly the error vanished when i did Project Clean Build..

Comment: You missed step one :D

Comment: Yeah.. My bad.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            print(json)
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
        }
```

Comment: Doesnt works.. giving same error.. Thanks for help.. been stuck in this for a while.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works

```
let json = JSON(result1)
```

Also there is a possibility that the result value is string. For that try this -

```
if let dataFromString = result1.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
    let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
}
```

Let me know if any of this works for you else I will try to find out something else.

Comment: Hi, none of them worked.. Also the result value is 'Any', Are you suggesting to convert it to String before converting to 'Data'?